# Python BeatifulSoup find all divs returning empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all house listings from a portuguese real estate agency website. I'm using the following small piece of code:

```py
import requests
import bs4
import os

REAL_ESTATE_AGENCY_URL= os.getenv('REAL_ESTATE_AGENCY_URL')

response = requests.get(REAL_ESTATE_AGENCY_URL)
response.raise_for_status()
content = response.text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

all_listings = soup.find_all(name="div", class_="listing-card")
print(all_listings)
```

The same link I'm using is: [this one](https://www.remax.pt/comprar?searchQueryState=%7B%22regionName%22:%22Porto%22,%22businessType%22:1,%22page%22:1,%22regionID%22:%2278%22,%22regionType%22:%22Region1ID%22,%22sort%22:%7B%22fieldToSort%22:%22ContractDate%22,%22order%22:1%7D,%22mapIsOpen%22:false,%22regionCoordinates%22:%7B%22latitude%22:41.21011650909249,%22longitude%22:-8.449367332491727%7D,%22regionZoom%22:9,%22prn%22:%22Porto%22,%22listingClass%22:1,%22listingTypes%22:%5B%2211%22,%221%22%5D,%22rooms%22:2,%22hasMultimedia%22:false%7D) (It was too long to put in plain text).
The `print` statement only prints an empty array. As you can see on the image below, the div containing all the information has a class of **listing-card**. I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

[image: inspect_printscreen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning empty result because the website is entirely depends on JavaScript.BeautifulSoup can't mimic data but You can grab data easily from api calls json response using only `requests` module.Here is the woriking example.

**Script:**

```
import requests
import json
body= {"filters":[{"field":"BusinessTypeID","value":"1","type":0},{"field":"NumberOfBedrooms","biggerThan":2,"type":4},{"field":"ListingTypeID","shouldValues":["11","1"],"type":2},{"field":"Region1ID","value":"78","type":0}],"sort":{"fieldToSort":"ContractDate","order":1}}
headers= {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
   }

api_url = "https://www.remax.pt/Api/Listing/MultiMatchSearch?page=1&searchValue=&size=20"


jsonData = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers).json()
#print(jsonData)
for item in jsonData['results']:
    price=item['listingPriceText']
    print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
125 000 €
137 500 €
132 500 €
142 500 €
132 500 €
152 500 €
132 500 €
142 500 €
135 000 €
145 000 €
110 000 €
198 000 €
120 000 €
260 000 €
265 000 €
305 000 €
252 500 €
500 000 €
75 000 €
142 000 €
```

Comment: It does seem to work. Yet, where did you get that URL from? (https://www.remax.pt/Api/Listing/MultiMatchSearch?page=1&searchValue=&size=20"). 

Also, on the field filters, where did the "type" come from? Or how did you find "ListingTypeID"?

Comment: From your above  link, I open it on chrome. Go to network tab > XHR then click on next page button from the url then you will see many requests will appear in name column then click on them one by one to see which one contains data click on header tab and if you want to see data then click on preview tab

Comment: Oh, now I see it yes! 
Last question, how can I know if I can use beautiful soup normally like I wanted to? Or when I need to make something like you just said? Where can I see that info so I know always what to do?

Thank you!

Comment: @TiagoRibeiro, in case of data extraction , it is always better practice to check whether the url  is dynamic or not before to start. You can do that disabled/enabled javascript from the browser. If you make disabled javascript  then if you see nothing in the url meaning blank then the url is dynamic meaning bs4 can't grab it then you have to use automation tool like selenium or api.